# How can I deal with a colleague who doesn't do work, is aggressive but got a promotion?

Tags: salary, colleagues, human-resources, unprofessional-behavior, promotion

Got a bit of a situation I'm not sure how to deal with. I had a run in with a colleague 2 weeks ago, they got upset over an email that was sent round and felt singled out by it, rather than speak about it they copied in the managers, incriminated themselves then got angry with me over it....as he ended up showing the management that he screwed up as he didn't read the documentation properly.

The next day I came in, sat at my desk to have the colleague come over, ask me if I'm going to apologise then aggressively tell me not to be an asshole like I'm being, asked me if I lacked empathy and if I had something like Asperger's, told me I'd be able to do my job properly when I get on his level and have his experience and then walked out of the workplace angry. I reported it to the manager in the end as the other colleagues around said he was way out of order, that he was threatening and that I really need to report it. But nothing was done about it. I then found out he has sworn at multiple colleagues and had multiple complaints against him. He has also been told off multiple times for not doing work or not having a professional attitude.

Since 2 weeks ago, a job in a higher position became available, which I managed to get the role. Which I thought 'brilliant I have managed to get away'. The colleague then applied for the same position and has now got it as well. He now works on the shift before mine and will need to hand things over to me.

The issue is, even with the aggression, not listening to anyone else at all and always being correct, and multiple complaints against him, they gave him a pay rise which seems to be above mine. He is also on the shift before mine, so he is expected to hand over any information/work to do to myself, which seeing he doesn't like me can screw me over easily.

Seems the interview they gave as well for the job type which is technical was done by people who knew nothing about the type or work/system. Anything could have been said. I have also found out that while I was given an interview for the role, they just gave it to the guy without one as they needed people.

Does anyone have any advice on how to deal with a situation like this? Or is there anything I can do to point out working with a colleague that doesn't like me isn't going to work out well?

Comment: How do you expect to deal with your management? Get another promotion? Ask for a further pay rise? You seem upset he got one... Ask to move to the shift before his so you hand over to him? Or polish your CV and move on from that environment. Given your assessment what else can you expect?

Comment: 1 person per shift unfortunately...so can't move shifts, and to be fair with the complaints against him...and lack of knowledge at all which was causing everyone distress...it seems like a kick in a teeth to ignore the stress he's caused people...they just promote him and give him a payrise...it seems like they did it just due to him being the oldest guy here

Comment: How do you know his pay rise details? Do you have the same manager as before?

Comment: @jonH not sure how I'm picking on the guy...haven't complained once to him, and I'm annoyed at management for the promotion and the payrise he got not him....the main issue is with it however he is going round being agressive since today to other members as he's now higher than them...and because he's senior now, he believes he is always right and everyone else is wrong...

Comment: He swore at you and basically told you you're incompetent, but you're not annoyed at him? Yet you're finding out his pay and already assuming he will 'screw you over' by sabotaging the work. There seems to be a mismatch.

Comment: Did you send the initial email that he felt singled him out? Was his assertion that he was singled out valid in any way (not saying it is, just curious)? It's not clear from the discussion how his ire got directed at you in the first place. Just trying to understand the details.

Comment: No problem that's fine to ask, no names were mentioned and yep sent an email to the whole team just asking people if they can make sure to follow the documentation as had a lot of calls recently from the customers being angry and that it was falling on the shift I was working on. People usually send emails round like this in the company, didn't mention anyone as didn't want to single them out unfairly...he copied in manager and replied commenting on a message he sent and incriminated himself...then blamed me as I sent the original email...

Comment: @kilisi I'm not finding out his pay....he freely started boasting to people about it...and started talking to other colleagues now like they are beneath him...and having only just started working with him on the same level I'm afraid he will screw me over as he has already messed up the handover of information, making me have to search around for everything and giving me as little detail as possible...

Comment: @kilisi and yep we have the same manager as before, they were unable to get a new manager in time so have kept them the same

Answer (score 46):

There are two questions here but only one is relevant.

**How do I deal with him handing off to me?**

Professionally. Basically start fresh. “Good afternoon, John. What do we have today?” He gives the handoff, you ask whatever legitimate questions you need to clarify and ensure you have the information you need. Basic closed loop communication, which everyone should be doing at every handoff.

If he is not providing information or is undermining you, then you talk to your manager, but not about the personality. You talk about how you need help getting good handoff.

If he undermines you by intentionally giving wrong info, then you document what info you were given.

Now if he is acting threatening or harassing, then you go to management with that complaint- not what happened before, what is happening now. And certainly do so if he is threatening your safety.

But start with the attitude that it’s a new role  as act like you are both new and starting fresh.

The other question in the OP **How do I deal with him getting an undeserved promotion, him getting the promotion without an interview when I had do so one, him getting more pay, etc?**

You don’t. It’s all irrelevant. They decided to promote him. They felt they knew what they needed to do so, but that they needed a little more info to promote you. When you are in management or own a company, you get to decide. As for the money, if you think you are underpaid, then look at one of the numerous questions in this board “How do I ask for a pay raise? What do I do if I feel I am underpaid? Etc.”

Comment: It might be that the colleague got "promoted" to get them away away from the manager and other people they are having issues with. It might also be a "promote out the door" kind of thing, where they put them in a position they can't do and either have cause to get rid of them, or they leave on their own. It's not a great situation for the OP, though. Documenting everything is exactly what the OP needs to CYA to put any problems on the actual cause, rather than "he said, she said".

Comment: The first part of this answer is like the [assume good faith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Assume_good_faith) principle used on this site, Wikipedia, and many others.  And it's a great principle.  If you treat your colleague cordially and professionally, he may respond in kind, and then things will be better.  (Or if not, at least you'll have done your best and given him no reason for it.)

Comment: very good answer!

Answer (score 12):

Let's review. You have a colleague who

- is abusive
- has a history of complaints filed against him by colleagues
- received a promotion which is likely undeserved
- received a bigger pay raise
- is likely to screw you over

You ask

> is there anything I can do to point out working with a colleague that doesn't like me isn't going to work out well?

Well... you can point it out, but don't hold your breath that it'll have an effect. They promoted him without an interview "as they needed people". They're unlikely to backpedal at this point.

> Does anyone have any advice on how to deal with a situation like this?

Yes, two things:

- document, document, document. Keeping a diary, flush with documentary evidence (printouts &etc) is now your favorite hobby.
- update your resume & start circulating it immediately

They're *promoting* jerks. Do you really expect it to get any better?

Comment: *They're promoting jerks. Do you really expect it to get any better?* -- nope.

Comment: Thank you...you seem to be the first person who understands the situation that's exactly how it is x.x funny enough...I've started doing the two things you mentioned...documenting it all, and updating CV